# Thymeleaf with Spring Security - how to check if user is logged in or not?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring Boot with Thymeleaf and Spring Security.
I've got a simple view with a login link. When the user logs in, I'd like to change login link to logout link.

I tried:

```
<div sec:authorize="#{isAuthenticated()}">
  <a th:href="@{/logout}">Log out</a>
</div>
<div sec:authorize="#{isAnonymous()}">
  <a th:href="@{/login}">Log in</a>
</div>
```

but it's not working - it displays both links.

EDIT:
I **solved** it. I had to register Thymeleaf dialect. In order to do this, I created a new config class, that creates SpringSecurityDialect bean:

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

    @Bean
    public SpringSecurityDialect springSecurityDialect(){
        return new SpringSecurityDialect();
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the exact same problem - thank you. It should not be so difficult to get this working.

Comment: The method 'SpringSecurityDialect' is only available in '2.1.0.RELEASE' version? I can not use the latest version => 2.1.2.RELEASE...

Comment: I had to use 3.0.2

Answer (score 46):

According to [thymeleaf docs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html)  no spel expression is required. This is not a th: attribute.

So you may try :

```
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">

<div sec:authorize="isAnonymous()">
```

Comment: Don't forget to import thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4 library to your project. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4

Comment: You'll need to include the [dependency for thymeleaf extras](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras) and also declare a [Bean for the SecurityDialect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42039384/3092830). The core [spring-boot-dependencies](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/d3849dc0c5c9bfd1364979089fe9e185d08245f9/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml) now includes the support for this dialect... not sure what that does about creating the Bean however.

Answer (score 4):

also you can use:

```
<ul>
  <li sec:authorize="isAnonymous()"><a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a></li>
  <li sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"><a class="nav-link" href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
  <li sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">Wellcome, <span sec:authentication="name"></span></li>
</ul>
```

to get de current loged user.

Answer (score 2):

Can also use `sec:authorize="isFullyAuthenticated()"` which checks if its an `anonymousUser` and `rememberMe`.

```
<div class="button-group" sec:authorize="!isFullyAuthenticated()">
    <a href="/login">Login</a>
    <a href="/register">Register</a>
</div>
<div class="button-group" sec:authorize="isFullyAuthenticated()">
    <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Following did not work for me for 3.0.4.RELEASE thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4:

```
<div sec:authorize="isAnonymous()">
```

Instead, following worked:

```
<div th:if="${#authentication == null}">
```

Comment: Thank you for giving this updated answer!