# Sec:authorize doesn't work in spring security 4

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

i'm trying to use spring security. I created two users in memory admin and users.

```
auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER");
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and this is my html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" 
xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/myStyle.css"/>
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myApp.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
</head>
<body ng-app="myStockApp">
<div ng-controller="mainctr">
<div data-ng-init="listArticles()"> 

<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">Only for admin</div>

//code ...
```

I would like that only the admin sees that div, but when i logged as a user, the div above appears, or it should be disappear. can you tell me where is the probleme ? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Could you replace in thymeleaf this

```
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">Only for admin</div>
```

with the following

```
<div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ADMIN')">Only for admin</div>
```

and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hi, Periklis, the same problem remain.

Comment: very strange, I use  <th:block sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">...</th:block> but it's equivalent to @PeriklisDouvitsas stuff

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you are using **spring security 4**, if you don't change your **thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity** for the correct one

Answer (score 0):

after searching and trying to understand the problem i found out that there is a problem with the dialect

you can see here how to add the dialect:
[How do I add Thymeleaf SpringSecurityDialect to spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42033368/how-do-i-add-thymeleaf-springsecuritydialect-to-spring-boot)

tl;dr
add this to your config

```
    @Bean
 public SpringSecurityDialect securityDialect() {
     return new SpringSecurityDialect();
 }
```