# SpringBoot show logout button for only users that are logged in without thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am currently looking for a solution on how to show the logout button only when a user is fully authenticated. This is for a personal project that I am doing. I want anonymous users to be able to view the home page if they are anonymous, then the sign-in and signup button would show, but if they are logged in, only the logout button will show. Like the title says, I want to be able to do it without **Thymeleaf**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use that:

```html
  <div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
    Text visible only to authenticated users.
  </div>
```

More details, examples and configuration you can find [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-thymeleaf) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904176/thymeleaf-with-spring-security-how-to-check-if-user-is-logged-in-or-not)(a similar topic on the Stackoverflow).