# Can not hide elements

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I am using these in my pom:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Now I am trying to hide an html element from unauthenticated users like below:

```
<a sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" href="/index" th:href="@{/index}"....

<a sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ADMIN')" href="/otherpage"......
```

But no matter if the user is authenticated or not, these elements are always visible. What I am missing here?

When I tried to follow this - [Thymeleaf with Spring Security - how to check if user is logged in or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904176/thymeleaf-with-spring-security-how-to-check-if-user-is-logged-in-or-not)
I am getting this error:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.ConfigurationException: The Spring-version-specific infrastructure could not create utility for the specific version of Spring being used. Currently only Spring 5.x is supported.

2022-12-28 11:58:05,233 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] [DirectJDKLog.java:175] --Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler processing failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.util.SpringVersionSpecificUtils] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.util.SpringVersionSpecificUtils
```

So, now, with Thymeleaf 3.1 and SpringBoot 3.x (security 6.x) what are the options or alternatives?

Comment: try [thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change that helped me when applied was in the pom.xml
I changed thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5 to thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6
and specified the version for the dependency.

---

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

---

I also added this configuration:

---

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity6.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect;

@Configuration
public class LeafConfig {

    @Bean
    public SpringSecurityDialect springSecurityDialect(){
        return new SpringSecurityDialect();
    }

}
```

Comment: I did this in a Spring Framework project, not boot. It didn't work :(